# Как спарсить все значения в списке по ключу?

Tags: python, list

Всем привет! Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему:
Есть список

```
[
    {
        'name': 'Afghanistan',
        'code': 'AF',
        'name_loc': {
            'ru': 'Афганистан',
            'en': 'Afghanistan'
        }
    },
    {
        'name': 'Åland Islands',
        'code': 'AX',
        'name_loc': {
            'ru': 'Аландские о-ва',
            'en': 'Åland Islands'
        }
    }
]
```

как наиболее оптимально пройтись по данному списку и вытащить все значения по ключу `"code"`?
как итог хотелось вот такое (список может быть разной длины):

```
list_code = ['AF', 'AX']
```

Comment: `list_code = [x['code'] for x in list]`

Comment: Спасибо большое! очень помогли

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут *getElements* принимает два аргумента (список словарей, ключ для поиска). Возвращает список данных поиска.

```
lists = [
    {
        'name': 'Afghanistan',
        'code': 'AF',
        'name_loc': {
            'ru': 'Афганистан',
            'en': 'Afghanistan'
        }
    },
    {
        'name': 'Åland Islands',
        'code': 'AX',
        'name_loc': {
            'ru': 'Аландские о-ва',
            'en': 'Åland Islands'
        }
    }
]

def getElements(list_objects, key):
    return list(map(lambda item: item[key], list_objects))

list_code = getElements(lists, 'code')

print(list_code)
```

Вывод в консоли

[image: Вывод в консоли]

Comment: `list_code = getElement(lists, 'code')` чет у тебя буква пропущена.